# Artifactory, howto create new layout from scratch

Tags: artifactory

Artifactory OSS 5.4.6.rev 50406900

Logged in as admin

Trying to follow instructions here...
https://www.jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-create-simple-versioning-custom-layout-in-artifactory/

```
Step 1)  First we will need to create a simple layout. In Artifactory, got to [Admin] --> [Repositories] --> [Layout], then click on "New"
```

I get to the Layout area but there is no "New" to click.  Where is this supposed to be?

I read elsewhere that it's also possible to copy an existing layout and modify that to create a new one.  How does one copy an existing layout?

Should admin be good enough to do this sort of thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, custom layouts are an Artifactory PRO feature and are not available in the OSS version.

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts

HTH,

Or

Comment: OK, that explains it.  Thanks.